# How to access json child with .json promise in Vue.js

Tags: json, vue.js, promise

Vue code:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#v-for-object3',
    data: function () {
        return {
            layers: []
        }
    },
    created() {

        var apiURL = "http://.../layers.json";

        var username = '';
        var password = '';

        fetch(apiURL, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: new Headers({
                'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ":" + password),
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }),

        })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(res => (this.layers = res))
            .catch(error => console.log(error));

    }

})
```

JSON format via url

```
layers  
  layer 
    0   
        name    "name1"
        href    "http://tttttttt.json"
    1   
        name    "name2"
        href    "http://iiiiiiii.json"
```

Print console

```
{ "layer": 
[ 
{ "name": "name1", "href": "http://tttttttt.json" }, 
{ "name": "name2", "href": "http://iiiiiiii.json" }
 ] }
```

layers contain 
`{ "layer": [ { "name": "name1", "href": "http:" }, { "name": "name2", "href": "http:" }..`
It's not an Array ?, how to change this code for layers [] contains child attributes JSON for display:
ex:

```html
<ul id="v-for-object3" class="userWrap">
    <li v-for="(layer, index) in layers" :item="layer" :key="index" class="layer">
        <h2>{{ index }}</h2>
        <span>
            Layer: <strong>{{layer }}</strong>
        </span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

How to access json child with .json promise in Vue.js?

Comment: Are you just looking for `v-for="(layer, index) in layers.layer"`?

Comment: with v-for="(layer, index) in layers.layer no rows display.

Comment: v-for="(layer, index) in layers" :item="layer" :key="index" just 1 row with all json

Comment: Given the data format you described the `v-for` I suggested should work. Alternatively you could use `.then(res => (this.layers = res.layer))` to pull out the array at that point. Unless you meant that there's also a `layers` property within the JSON, in which case it would be either `v-for="(layer, index) in layers.layers.layer"` or `.then(res => (this.layers = res.layers.layer))`. The description of the data format in the question is a little ambiguous.

Comment: Also, what does *'It's not a tab'* mean?

Comment: .then(res => (this.layers = res.layer)) dont work : Error in render: "TypeError: layers is undefined"

Comment: .then(res => (this.layers = res.layers.layer)) no error no display
'It's not a tab' not an array

Comment: Is the JSON returned by the server `{"layer":[...]}` or `{"layers":{"layer":[...]}}` or something else entirely? Please update the question to be clear and unambiguous so that there is no doubt about precisely what format your server is returning.

Comment: Would you do a `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.layers)` or `console.log(this.layers.layer.length)` and post the code result here. The `v-for="(layer, index) in layers.layer` should provide you an actual list.

Comment: `code`this.layers.length = 0`code`

Comment: I update the question JSON print in console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the `fetch` use:

```js
fetch(apiURL, {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: new Headers({
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ":" + password),
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }),
})
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(res => {
    console.log('in fetch callback')
    console.log(res)
    console.log(Object.keys(res))
    console.log(this.layers)
    this.layers = res.layers.layer
    console.log(this.layers)
    console.log(Array.isArray(this.layers))
  })
  .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Obviously the console logging isn't required but it should allow you to confirm that everything is working correctly. The logging at the start checks the value of `res`. Then it logs the initial value of `this.layers`, which should be an empty array. The next value should be the populated array, with 2 items. The final check should just log `true`, confirming that we really are dealing with an array and not some wrapper object.

Then, for the template loop:

```html
<li v-for="(layer, index) in layers" :key="index" class="layer">
  <h2>{{ index }}</h2>
  <span>
    Layer: <strong>{{ layer.name }}</strong>
  </span>
</li>
```

I've removed the `:item="layer"` because that wasn't doing anything useful. I've also changed `{{ layer }}` to `{{ layer.name }}`, which isn't strictly necessary either but it seems more likely to be what you'd actually want.

Effectively the template code is the same as it was in the original question. Even if you make no changes to the template it should work. However, it is important to ensure that you undo any changes that you've made to the template since posting the question. If you combine all of the suggestions that have been made in the comments they'll end up cancelling out and it won't work.

Comment: thanks but no results, console.log :
Array []
undefined
false

Comment: @bipbip If you put `console.log(res)` inside that callback what do you get?

Comment: Response { type: "cors", url: "http://url/rest/layers.json", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, statusText: "OK", headers: Headers, body: ReadableStream, bodyUsed: false }

Comment: @bipbip I have updated my answer to include the full `fetch` code as your last comment implies that you had removed the `.json()` call, which was not my intention.

Comment: in fetch callback
Object { layers: {…} }
Array [ "layers" ]
Array []
undefined
false

Comment: Object { layers: {…} } contains:

{…}
​
layers: {…}
​​
layer: (7) […]
​​​
0: Object { name: "name1", href: "http://url.json" }
​​​
1: Object { name: "name2", href: "http://url.json" }

Comment: @bipbip I have updated my answer again. Based on your latest comment I believe it should be `this.layers = res.layers.layer`. However, I have suggested this before and you claimed that it didn't work. Please attempt to do some debugging of the problem yourself. It feels like you are implementing my suggestions without attempting to understand them. This should be a trivial problem to solve but I can only speculate about the relevant data structure based on the information you've provided. You have the luxury of seeing the problem first-hand, which makes debugging much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment:

"v-for="(layer, index) in layers" :item="layer" :key="index" just 1 row with all json – bipbip"

It looks to me that the response you are getting from calling that endpoint is returning an array with a single element which contains the layers object you described, thats why you are seeing all the json object displayed. So in that case this should fix it:

```
.then(res => (this.layers = res[0].layer))
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: if res[0].layer   error = TypeError: "res[0] is undefined"